# Nice way to query all objects including modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I'm looking for a nice and comfortable way to gather all objects from the object context - including the added and modified.
I now the stuff about ObjectStateManager and that you can get the objects their.
But my problem is, if a query the object context with linq, i have to do the same query to the modified and added objects and merge them together. this is not really comfortable and always a few lines of code. is there a way to wrap this nicely?

I tried something like this:

```
new QueryWrapper<User>(ctx.Users).Where(u => u.Name.StartsWith("A"));
```

I then tried to implement my own IQueryable and my own IQueryProvider to wrap this stuff up and get the expression tree that is executed. My idea was then to take this expression tree and let it run against the entity framework and the inmemory collection where i get the modified and added objects.
I came pretty far, here we go:

```
public class InMemoryQuery<T> : IQueryable<T> 
{

    private readonly IQueryable<T> _queryable;

    public InMemoryQuery(IQueryable<T> queryable)
    {
        _queryable = queryable;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._queryable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return this._queryable.Expression; }
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            return new InMemoryQueryProvider(this._queryable.Provider);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Query Provider

```
public class InMemoryQueryProvider : IQueryProvider
    {

    private readonly IQueryProvider _innerprovider;

    public InMemoryQueryProvider(IQueryProvider innerprovider)
    {
        _innerprovider = innerprovider;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new InMemoryQuery<TElement>(this._innerprovider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression));
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This works so far and i am able to get the expression tree that should be executed in the InMemoryQuery.GetEnumerator Method. Great!
My problem is that this query contains the entity framework base expression as well, something like:

```
Convert(value(ObjectSet`1[EFQueryProviderTest.tbl_Contact]))
    .MergeAs(AppendOnly).Where(n => n.Name.StartsWith("A"))
```

But i only need the part from .Where(...) on.
Do you know what i mean? I then want to try to execute this part of the query against the objects delivered from the object state manager.

What do you think? Is this possible? Can you help me to achieve this? Or am i going into the completely wrong direction? is there a better way?

Comment: I don't really have a suggestion on your actual problem, just wondering if you really _need_ to query objects in the ObjectStateManager. The context is meant to be short lived, single transaction or single request (in the case of a web app). Maybe rethink the use of the context altogether.

Comment: Hi joe, thank you for your reply. Of course youare right. But it is no webapp and i have a relatively complex save/cancel scenario. Means the user can change a lot of tables and commit or discard it at once. How would you achieve this?